# AbstractTableModel - don't return getRowCount()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

here is code where i add table model to my table:

```
table = new JTable(new TerminiTableModel());
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

then i made this class TerminiTableModel() and here is just a simple generated code where i want to get column cound and row count... Column count works just fine and add 3 columns to my table ("Termini", "Ime i prezime" and "Napomena"). When i add that line in getRowCount, i get error and cant even compile it... Here is code... I made search about this and just cant figure it out... :-/

```
public class TerminiTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel {

    protected TableModel tableModel;

    private String[] columnNames = {"Termin", "Ime i prezime", "Napomena"};
    private String[] data = {"7:00", "8:00", "9:00" , "10:00" , "11:00" , "12:00" };

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;   //  <<----- this line is problem
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col > 0) {
            return true;
        } else
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object data, int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Solution is probably simple, but i need some help with this... 
Thank You in advance...

Comment: Hi, can we see what error you are getting or what Exception has been thrown.

Comment: The code does compile!

Comment: does your TableModel have a method called getRowCount? can't find any errors in the code you have currently provided. Im thinking the issue might be that you are trying to override something that doesn't exist, or that the getRowCount in TabelModel returns something else then a int. Please post the code in TabelModel/AbstractTabelModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT based on commnets

rows in JTable is based on two Dimensional arrays, then

```
private String[] data = {"7:00", "8:00", "9:00" , "10:00" , "11:00" , "12:00" };
```

should be

```
private String[][] data = {{"7:00", null, null}, {"8:00", null, null}, 
            {"9:00", null, null}, {"10:00", null, null}, {"11:00", null, null}, 
            {"12:00", null, null}};
```

for defined Columns

[image]

from code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTable {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
    private JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane();
    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    private JTable dialogTable = new JTable(tableModel);

    public MyTable() {
        dialogTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dialogTable.getPreferredSize());
        tableScroll = new JScrollPane(dialogTable, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.add(tableScroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(dialogTable.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(dialogTable.getColumnCount());
        System.out.println(tableModel.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(tableModel.getColumnCount());
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"Termin", "Ime i prezime", "Napomena"};
        private String[][] data = {{"7:00", null, null}, {"8:00", null, null}, 
            {"9:00", null, null}, {"10:00", null, null}, {"11:00", null, null}, 
            {"12:00", null, null}};

        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnNames) {
            switch (columnNames) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;//return Date.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;//return Double.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;//return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;   //  <<----- this line is problem
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object data, int row, int col) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mKorbel :D that helped A LOT :) i cant vot up ur answer bcs i need some reputation, but im very grateful :D

Comment: you are welcome, btw everything is in Oracle tutorial, important rest is here :-)

Comment: "AbstractTableModel returns columnNames.length and data.length correctly" - i never wrote that.. i said columnCount works fine.. not rowCount :)

Comment: good you edited the (at least confusing but essintially incorrect) part out :-)  @Mlad3n that's a quote from mKorbels unedited answer

Comment: @Reimenus - Accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The error caused is this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which is caused by not specifying the column class:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
   return String.class;
}
```

Also `getValueAt` doesnt return any data. You are using a 1D array to store data, Given that `JTable` data is represented in rows & columns you would need to use a 2D array.

Comment: thx for answer.. im sorry if question wa sstupid.. i  got a lot help here.. and why i got -1 at my question ?

Comment: Possibly because you didnt state what the exact error was originally?

Comment: i sad what was my problem and i gave code to You all so u can see where i made misstake... Whoever gave me -1, TY :)

Comment: Thank You :) looking forward to use this helpful site more :)